# USB flash drive keeps stopping copying

Tags: linux, usb

I'm trying to copy about 10 GB from Linux to my 16GB USB flash drive(currently with 11GB free memory, NTFS). First, 8GB were copying quite quickly, but then the flash drive started to repeatedly stop copying for a while.

It copies about thousand files and then takes a break for a minute or so. What could the problem be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you have reached the limit the wear-leveling algorithm can handle.

The drive is busy erasing blocks to hold your files (probably made much worse by the fact that NTFS is a journaling file system). You will get a much better performance if you pack all the files into a single archieve like a TAR or a zip/gz with a low compression level. Formatting the drive as FAT32 or ex-FAT may help a bit as well.